# How to create file as given user with restricted permissions atomically

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to convert the following commands to atomic one-liner… possible?

```
echo foo | sudo -u sun tee bar.private
chmod 600 bar.private
```

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What you are looking for is [`umask`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/umask)

Comment: @ThoriumBR Trying to create a file as given user and set its permissions in one atomic operation (in other words, I don’t want file to be ever readable by other users).

Comment: @MechMK1 Stumbled upon `umask`… would you happen to know how to reset umask to OS default? What I don’t like about using `umask` is syntax… have to set umask and then reset it to OS default… perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: `sudo touch bar.private ; sudo chmod 600 bar.private ; echo foo | sudo tee bar.private`. This creates an empty file, change its permissions, and uses `tee` to write on it. It don't even need to be atomic, you can create the file today, change the permissions tomorrow and write to it in a week.

Comment: `umask` is confined to the current shell. You can set `umask` in one terminal, do whatever you want, close the terminal, done. No need to "reset umask to default", it will always be default. To change `umask` for all shells you need to put it on `~/.bash_profile` (if you use bash as shell) so every shell will have the changed `umask`.

Comment: @ThoriumBR Interesting… so if I set `umask` inside of Bash script, permissions only apply within context of script, correct?

Comment: Yes, as soon as the script finishes, the default `umask` applies.

Comment: @ThoriumBR, though if you create the file with loose permissions at first, an attacker could in theory open it just after it's created, and if kept open, the fd to the file could still be used to read the file after the permissions were changed.

Comment: @ilkkachu possible, but that kind of attack would be very, very specific and I don't think anyone would execute such attack in real life.

Comment: @ThoriumBR, yes, the window is narrow, and for an ad hoc use it's probably not a big problem. But if some well-known and widely used piece of software would do that in a context where reading the file would allow privilege escalation, it just might be discovered the wrong way at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Permissions of newly-created files are modified by the process umask, which works in inverse: the bits *set* in the umask will be *cleared* in the resulting permissions. So setting the umask to `0077`, would make most utilities create files with permissions `0600`.

By default, sudo inherits a stricter umask from the environment it's started in, so you could do something like this:

```
echo foo | (umask 0077; sudo -u sun tee bar.private)
```

and the file would be created with permissions `0600`.

What `sudo` actually does, is that it does a bitwise *and* of the umask in the environment, and the umask set in the [configuration file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sudoers.5.html) (`umask` option, defaulting to `0022`). So by default you can't have the `tee` run with an umask of `0000`, it'll turn to `0022` instead. But we're making it stricter here, and that works.

Of course, it's possible that the configuration sets the umask to something else, perhaps even with `umask_override`, which might make it looser, and in addition there might be some PAM module to also modify it. In that case, you could have sudo run a shell that sets the umask and then runs the command:

```
echo foo | sudo -u sun sh -c 'umask 077; tee bar.private'
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!